# prove for all $y_1,y_2 ...,y_n>0, \frac{y_1}{y_2}+\frac{y_2}{y_3}+...+\frac{y_n}{y_1}\geq n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you even approach such a question? I cant think of how AM-GM inequality or logs could apply. I also tried let $RHS =  ny_1y_2...y_n$ and it doesnt seem lead anywhere either.

Comment: Have you tried AM-GM? On left there are $n$ terms.

Comment: Divide both sides by $n$ so the application of AM-GM becomes more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a very straightforward application of the AM-GM inequality, $\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n} >= \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2...a_n}$.

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{y_1}{y_2}+\frac{y_2}{y_3}+...+\frac{y_n}{y_1} \right) \geq \sqrt[n]{ \frac{y_1}{y_2} \times \frac{y_2}{y_3} \times \cdots\times\frac{y_n}{y_1}}=1.
\end{eqnarray*}